# Why preprocessed file of simple C++ source file contains thousands lines of code?

Tags: c++, compilation, iostream, preprocessor

I am learning C++. I learned a little about the C++ compilation process and the first step of the compilation process is preprocessing. I am curious what happens to source file after preprocessing so I wrote a few lines of code in C++. Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define PI 3.1416
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    cout << "The value of PI is: " << PI << '\n'; 
}
```

Not more than ten lines of code.

I use this compiler flag `g++ -E main.cpp > main.p` so the preprocessed file is `main.p`.
The preprocessed file `main.p` contains 28634 lines of code.

First 15 lines of `main.p` looks like:

```
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "/usr/include/c++/9/iostream" 1 3
# 36 "/usr/include/c++/9/iostream" 3
       
# 37 "/usr/include/c++/9/iostream" 3

# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++config.h" 1 3
# 252 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++config.h" 3

# 252 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++config.h" 3
```

And last 10 lines of `main.p` looks like:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    cout << "The value of PI is: " << 3.1416 << '\n';
}
```

Why do `main.p` contains so many lines of code? My hypothesis (Please correct me if I am wrong) is that all the codes used to build `iostream` library are included in `main.p` file, if so then isn't binary or executable of `main.cpp` unnecessarily big?

Comment: That's just how `#include` directive works. It reads the filename and replaces `#include` with the content of that file (recursively). `iostream` is a huge header, so including it is a (tiny, but still) overhead to compilation time and binary size.

Comment: Yes, all includes are recursively copy pasted to each translation unit.

Comment: Your hypothesis is correct, as stated in the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include). That is unrelated to the size of the executable.

Comment: The compiler is pretty smart - especially when you turn on optimizations. It will take the pre-processed source file and only include the actually needed bits in the final binary. Source size does not equal binary size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct: the entire contents of the `iostream` header are included in the preprocessor output. And this happens transitively: every header included by `iostream` is also included, and so on. This is essentially what `#include` means!

However, this does not mean that your executable will be big:

- Headers typically contain only declarations, not implementations. Declarations don't contain any executable code. The actual implementation is in a shared library.
- Many headers in the standard library contain just templates, which don't emit any code until they're instantiated.
- Inline implementations *are* allowed in headers, but they are inlined in the call site, so as long as you don't call them they won't be compiled either.

Comment: So If I include `iostream` multiple times in multiple files in a C++ program, all of these preprocessed files of source file contain all the declarations from `iostream` header? If so that seems redundant, right?

Comment: This is one reason why you write include guards in headers: `#ifndef IOSTREAM_INCLUDED` `#define IOSTREAM_INCLUDED` ... actual contents ... `#endif`. If you're shocked at the stupidity of the preprocessor, remember that it's been basically unchanged since the first versions of the C language in the 1960s, and has been designed to work within the limitations of computers back then.

Comment: I had no idea about header guards before your comment(I am neophyte in C++) , after little Googling I think I have a tiny idea about it. Don't you think `module` in C++ 20 would help in this regard? (sorry if knowing `module` seems too forward for a newcomer in C++).

Comment: @Yousuf: It *better*; this is why `module` was added.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` directive literally pastes content of included file into the final file for compilation. For C++, a single include can tug along a lot of other includes from the included file, balooning the resulting file.

This is just the way C++ includes work. The executable file size would contain the code required to support your functionality, and there is no way around it.

Comment: Don't think that module(C++ 20) would help in this regard?